# Java 1.8 FileOutputStream Creating a Directory

Tags: java, io, java-io, fileoutputstream

I seem to be having a problem with the 1.8 JDK this project was built using the 1.7 JDK but i'm having a problem i can't quite understand.

So i have a ConfigReader Class.

```
    public class ConfigReader {
    private static ConfigReader _inst;

    public static ConfigReader GetInstance(){
        if(_inst == null){
            _inst = new ConfigReader();
        }
        return _inst;
    }

    private String basePath =  "Config/";

    public <T extends Serializable> void Write(T in, String filename)
    {
        String path = basePath+filename+".bin";
        try
        {   
            File f = new File(path);
            f.mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream fileOut =
            new FileOutputStream(path);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(in);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Saved config file '"+path+"'");
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to create config file '"+path+"'");
        }
    }

    public boolean ConfigExists(String filename)
    {
        String path = basePath+filename+".bin";
        File finfo = new File(path);
        return finfo.exists();
    }

    public <T extends Serializable> T Read(T readin, String filename)
    {
        String path = basePath+filename+".bin";
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            readin = (T) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
            return readin;
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to read '"+path+"'");
            return null;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to unserialize '"+path+"'");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason when the Write Method is called it's creating directories E.G

Reading a file:

```
boolean cfgExists = ConfigReader.GetInstance().ConfigExists("Global.cfg");
if(_inst == null && !cfgExists){
    _inst = new Global();
}else if(cfgExists){
    _inst = ConfigReader.GetInstance().Read(_inst, "Global.cfg");
}
```

Writing a file:

```
ConfigReader.GetInstance().Write(this, "Global.cfg");
```

I end up with the empty directory "Global.cfg.bin" not a file. i'm slightly confused why this is now happening...

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` has nothing to do with it, or serialization either.

Comment: @EJP well it has something to do with it it's writing the file content and you can't write file contents into a folder neds to be a File. so it should be throwing an error... but it's not.

Comment: No. The file is created, or not, by `FileOutputStream,` and written to, or not, ditto. The `ObjectOutputStream` is constructed afterwards and does no I/O of its own, deleating it all to the `FileOutputStream.` Ergo it has nothing do with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `f.mkdirs()` is creating the directory with a path that is identical to your intended file path. Call `f.getParentFile().mkdirs()` instead and that should clear it up.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think it ever did. At the least, nothing in the javadoc going all the way back to 1.5.0 would indicate that it would treat names with periods in them as Files and not dirs ... but who really knows? :)

Comment: @MartinBarker It never did.